# How do you add a texture to a line on the iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, core-graphics

I am drawing lines using the, CGContextBeginPath, CGContextMoveToPoint, CGContextAddLineToPoint, etc, etc, CGContextStrokePath methods.  I would like to apply a texture to these lines as well.

Can someone point me to the Apple doc's, a blog that explains how, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked this question in another forum and was given a good answer there.  Here is the link to the answer.

http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/How-do-you-add-a-texture-to-a-line-on-the-iPhone-iPad-tp3500298p3500298.html;cid=1304641992170-368